# Missing a using directive or an assembly reference error when I'm not missing anything

Tags: visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I have a solution with 4 projects. In the first one I reference the other three, not with Browse, but with Add reference->Project tab.

I have all three using statements in the beginning.

The program works fine. I tested it and it works. But I'm not able to build it.

I get the error "Missing a using directive or an assembly reference".

None of my projects are on client profile. (I think .Net 2.0 doesn't even have client profile).

Why is VS doing this? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean build was the solution. Duh.